# Regarding the union of certain affine Hyperplanes being closed

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $F$ be the union of all affine hyperplanes $\Pi\subset\mathbb{C}^n\setminus X$. It is said that $F$ is a closed set.

The proof goes like this:
If $x_j\in F$ then we can find affine hyperplanes ${\Pi}_j\subset\mathbb{C}^n\setminus X$ such that $x_j\in{\Pi}_j$. If $x_j\longrightarrow x$ then we can choose a subsequence ${\Pi}_{jk}$ converging to an affine hyperplane $\Pi\subset\mathbb{C}^n\setminus X$, and since $x\in \Pi$, it follows that $F$ is closed.

My question is:

1. How are we getting this subsequence ${\Pi}_{jk}$ and how does ${\Pi}_{jk}$ converge to $\Pi$?
2. Why does $x$ belong to $\Pi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about hyperplanes that converge needs indeed a good definition. What you're reading seems loosy on this point. Here is a rigorous explanation .

Think of the affine hyperplane $\Pi_j \subset \mathbb{C}^n \setminus X $ as the hyperplane $\{ x_j + v \, | \, \langle v, v_j \rangle =0\}$ for a normed $1$ vector $v_j$. This is the hyperplane passing by $x_j$ and orthogonal to $v_j$.

Then $(v_j)$ is a sequence in the compact unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$ so there is a subsequence $v_{j_k}$ that converges to some $v_0$. Then take $\Pi$ to be the orthogonal of $v_0$ passing by $x$ : $\{ x+v \, | \, \langle v,v_0 \rangle \}$.

Using the openness of $X$, show that $\Pi$ is indeed in $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$. Basically, if $x+v$ were in $X$, there would be $x_{j_k} + w_k \in \Pi_{j_k}$ tending to $x+v$ and so would be in $X$.